# Undefined variable in view - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to get the list of users from DB in Laravel but view
doesn't recognize variable from controller. The name of the table in
DB is korisnik.

Model.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
class model {  
 public function dohvatiKorisnike() {
   return DB::table('korisnik')->get();
 }
}
```

KontrolerProba.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\model;

class KontrolerProba {
 public function index(){
   $korisnik = new model();
   $korisniciUpit = $korisnik->dohvatiKorisnike();
   $podaci = array();
   $podaci['korisnik'] = $korisniciUpit;

   return view('welcome', $podaci);
 }
}
```

welcome.blade.php

```
@foreach($korisnici as $korisnik)
 <p{{ $korisnik->korisnicko_ime }} </p>
@endforeach
```

*Undefined variable: korisnici (View:
C:\wamp64\www\test\resources\views\welcome.blade.php)*

Comment: Well you are sending podaci so you have to print `$podaci` variable just give it a try with `@php(dump($podaci))` in your blade template

Comment: I get undefined variable podaci error..

Comment: then try this `return view('welcome', compact('podaci'))`; and dont forget `extends Controller`

Comment: You have used wrong variable name please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Pass controller data in view through two methods:

1. Using `compact`
2. Using `with()` method

```
 $data['korisnik'] = $korisniciUpit;     
 return view('welcome')->with($data);
```

Then access in view like `$korisnik->column_name`

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong variable.

Try :

```
@foreach($korisnik as $value)
 <p> {{ $value->korisnicko_ime }} </p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

The proble is . You are passing `korisnik` and trying to get the data with `korisnici`

Try this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class KontrolerProba {
 public function index(){
 $korisniciUpit = DB::table('korisnik')->get();
 $data['korisnik'] = $korisniciUpit;
 return view('welcome', $data);
 }
}
```

On your `Welcome.blade.php`

```
@foreach($korisnik as $value)
   <p{{ $value->korisnicko_ime }} </p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Did you apply as my answer is !

Comment: Well i need model and controller to be separated, i can't use them in same file.

Comment: Well did you create an model for this table `korisnik` !

Comment: @user3047285 Well did you create an model for this table korisnik !

Comment: Umm yes, i think i have?

Comment: Then just use instead of `$korisniciUpit = DB::table('korisnik')->get(); ` Use `$korisniciUpit = Korisnik::all();` Don't forget to integrate at top `Use App\Korisnik;`

Answer (score 0):

Lets follow the control steps;

1-) Are you sure returned data from your query is not null ?
2-) laravel returns the queries in object form, to not to confuse a lot, i suggest you to create an empty object before you fill. So lets change the code a bit.

```
$podaci = (object)null;
$podaci->korisnik = $korisniciUpit;
```

Laravel also offers changing the variable name on view... After a while you would have problem with changing all variables and messes around.

```
return view('welcome')->with(['data' => $podaci]);
```

to test your passing variable please check in your view;

```
var_dump($data);
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: I have tried with empty object and with return view('welcome')->with(['data' => $podaci]); and i get the same error :( Can you try it on your end please? Thanks.

Comment: The example has been applied into many projects, so it is surely working. Please check all the parameters if they contain some value. If not;<br>

$podaci->korisnik = "hello";
Debug it.